# Weird behavior when trying to Animate a sprite image with html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Au6br/2/

As you can see, the animation is weird and this is due to the sprites image I am using. Does anyone know any work around to fix the animation?

```
if (keydown.right) {
    character.x += character.sp;
    character.Pos = 3;
    character.Row++;
    if (character.Row == 4)
        character.Row = 0;
}
if (character.x > (cw-character.w)) {
    character.x = cw - character.w;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are not copying the correct part of your sprite image onto the canvas – so figure out what that right part is and how to calculate it’s position within the image correctly …

Comment: i am not sure this is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're clearly taking the wrong part of the sprite sheet.

I had a quick look, and your running sprites are vertically spaced-out with a height of 19 pixels, but you seem to be using 23 in your code. Also, you had what I assume is a typo where you were using the character width to calculate the y-coord of the image's source in your sprite-sheet, rather than the character's height. So changing that to:

```
ctx.drawImage(charImg, this.Pos * this.w, this.h * this.Row, this.w, this.h, this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
```

and setting your character's height to 19 (i.e. `this.h` in the above) gets you to here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Au6br/8/

which is what I assume you want.